# How to retrive facts asserted by a rule having particular name?

Tags: clips

I have certain template defined as follows:

```
(deftemplate action
    (slot name)
    (slot field)
    (slot value))
```

I have other rules which will use other facts to assert the action fact.

Now I want to retrieve only the fact with template action.

For now, I am using `find-fact` to retrieve, but here I have to use query which I do not want to provide.

```
(find-fact ((?fact action)) (= (str-compare ?fact:name 'Action1') 0))
```

I want all facts with template action and do not want to write a loop over all names with Action1, Action2 etc..

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         CLIPS (6.31 4/1/19)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate action
    (slot name)
    (slot field)
    (slot value))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts actions
   (action (name Action1) (field x) (value 3))
   (action (name Action2) (field y) (value 4))
   (action (name Action3) (field z) (value 5)))
CLIPS>        
(defrule find-Action1
   (action (name Action1))
   =>)
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      find-Action1: f-1
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (action (name Action1) (field x) (value 3))
f-2     (action (name Action2) (field y) (value 4))
f-3     (action (name Action3) (field z) (value 5))
For a total of 4 facts.
CLIPS>
```